# UILabel with fixed width and 1 line, content sometimes not that precisely align to training with ellipsis

Tags: ios, objective-c, label, uilabel

I have a common scenario that align `Title Label To Logo Image 5 points`, so use auto-layout this is easy to complete,but the problem is that the title label and logo image background color are all clear, then when the title is exceed width of label, the ellipsis mark auto-added in the end has some space between the right end of the UILabel, then the title label appears more far away from the logo behind.

Now my UILabel has fixed width and set only 1 line to trigger ability of auto-ellipsis of UILabel, then content sometimes not that precisely align to training with ellipsis. It appears depends on what content it needs to present. For example, if contents almost fit with label, then it's perfect align left n right, but if you add one more characteristic to content then this weird condition appears.

so is there anyway to precisely let me control the ellipsis position move to the end of label, without that blank space to the right;

Example:

[image: just like this]

[image: constraints]

### I just wanna to delete the blank-space in the end of UILabel.

Comment: did you gives fix width to label ?

Comment: @KKRocks yes. The label is defined fixed width and set one line.

Comment: can you elaborate your needs . i cant got your question.

Comment: @KKRocks i updated my question, waiting for your suggestion.

Comment: select your width constraint and make it less than or equal .

Comment: @Burnie777 actually no restriction of the content , all letters and numbers are allowed.

Comment: @KKRocks i set the width of my label less or equal to 200, and does'n get what i expect. the blank space exists as before.

Comment: did you give right or trailing constraint to label ?

Comment: @SevenJustin see my answer below

Comment: @SevenJustin see my answer.

Comment: @KKRocks the label's training is leading to logo behind

Comment: try my answer and remove older constraints .

Comment: @KKRocks it's the same, not the reason effect , can you successfully training with ellipsis?.

Comment: using my answer you can remove black-space in end of label . i have tested very well .

Comment: it's convenient to audio you from some chat platform and let me know the details about this question?

Answer (score 1):

As you've noticed, the `UILabel` frame can end up with a little extra space when the text is truncated. You cannot (as far as I can find) fix that with pure Autolayout, but you *can* fix it with a little bit of code.

Set a width constraint on your label, and assign it to an IBOutlet. You can then get the *actual* width of the truncated string and change the `.constant` on that `NSLayoutConstraint`:

```
@interface LabelTruncatingViewController ()
    // this is the label
    @property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UILabel *theLabel;
    // this is the width constraint of theLabel
    @property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet NSLayoutConstraint *theWidth;
@end

@implementation LabelTruncatingViewController

// on a button tap, for example
- (IBAction)fixLabel:(id)sender {

    _theWidth.constant = [self truncatedWidthFor:_theLabel withMaxWidth:80.0];

}

- (CGFloat)truncatedWidthFor:(UILabel *)aLabel withMaxWidth:(CGFloat)maxWidth {

    NSString *s = aLabel.text;

    if (s.length == 0) {
        return 0.0;
    }

    UIFont *f = aLabel.font;
    CGSize sz = CGSizeZero;

    // while the string is at least 1 character
    while (s.length > 0) {

        // append ellipsis
        NSString *t = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@…", s];

        // get the size of the string using the label's font
        sz = [t sizeWithAttributes:@{NSFontAttributeName: f}];

        // if the width of the substrint + ellipsis is less than the max width,
        //  break out of the while() loop
        if (sz.width <= maxWidth) {
            break;
        }

        // strip the last character from the end of the string
        s = [s substringToIndex:s.length - 1];

    }

    // labels don't like fractions
    return ceil(sz.width);

}

@end
```

Example: `UILabel` with default system font 17.0, text of `23323223999`, set to max width of 80.0, logo image constrained to 5-pts from label. Top image is *before* running this code, bottom image is *after* running this code.

[image]

Comment: @SevenJustin - You will have to be more clear about what you are trying to achieve, because it *looks* like gave you what you were asking for: a way to have the label size to the truncated text, leaving no extra space after the ellipsis "..."

Comment: Cool! But one question, if UILabel's text is Chinese, that method doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

This is normal because you use fixed width for the label and use fixed font size.

Try to use **Minimum font scale** to to fit all the content.

[image]

Comment: the scenario needs to present ellipsis when the content exceed the width not shrink the font size, so i don't know how to delete the bank space ....

Answer (score 0):

I do not think the the space is the issue, I think it is more a case of the label being setup not to show a partial letter or number... So it would **remove the last 2 visible chars and replace it with an ellipsis**, hence it looks like a space at the end (this is because an ellipsis is bigger than one char, yet smaller than two chars).

If I create 2 labels with equal width, one with text "1234" and the other "12345", the output is as follows...

[image]

Basically the label is right... Yet, I do not think iOS will allow partial chars to be shown.

Comment: Yes i know maybe this the right way Apple deals. So we can’t control this in a delicate way?

Comment: Not according to anything I have seen... or have dealt with.

Comment: OK Thanks for answering my question. If i get the corporate answer i will answer back to you !

Comment: @SevenJustin pleasure